# phonegap-plugin-push não funciona no iOS

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notification

Boa Tarde a todos!

Eu tenho um projeto IONIC onde estou usando o phonegap-plugin-push para enviar notificações Push.
No Android está funcionando muito bem, mas no iOS não funciona. Não aparece o Alert perguntando se eu desejo receber notificações e o Registration Event não é executado.

Eu já habilitei os Push Notifications no Apple Developer, estou usando os Provisioning corretos e os Certificados P12 corretos.

Meu código é este:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    console.log('>>>>>> DEVICE READY <<<<<<');
    handleNotificationReady();
});

function handleNotificationReady(){
    console.log('>>>> HandleNotificationReady <<<<');
    var pushNotification;

    if (device.platform == 'Android') {
        console.log('>>> Android, nice to meet you!');
        pushNotification = PushNotification.init({
            android: {
                senderID: '6610***',
                icon: 'icon'
            }
        });
    } else if (device.platform == 'iOS') {
        console.log('>>> iOS, nice to meet you!');
        pushNotification = PushNotification.init({
            ios: {
                alert: 'true',
                badge: 'true',
                sound: 'true'
            }
        });
    }

    pushNotification.on('registration', function(data) {
        console.log('>>>> REGISTRATION <<<<');
        console.log(data.registrationId);
    });

    pushNotification.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log('>>>> NOTIFICATION <<<<');
        console.log(data);
    });

    pushNotification.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('>>>> ERROR <<<<');
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

E o console:

```
`>>>>>> DEVICE READY <<<<<<
>>>> HandleNotificationReady <<<<
>>> iOS, nice to meet you!`
```

De acordo com o log, ele executa o INIT, mas não chega a Registrar.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que está errado.

Obrigada!